# Infinite continuous derivability

Tags: derivatives

Does a function exist so that

```
f(x) = 0    x <= 0
f(1) = 1
```

under the additional constraint that *all* derivatives of f shall be continuously differentiable in [0;1]?

I strongly suspect that this is impossible, but I can't come up with a proof.

Constructing an f(x) which is continuous up to its *n*th derivative (for arbitrary finite *n*) is obvious, but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: the standard example is $f(x)=\exp (-\frac 1{x^2})$ for $x>0$ scaled as you like to get the value at $x=1$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#Smooth_transition_functions

Comment: Further details here on math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328868/how-to-build-a-smooth-transition-function-explicitly

Comment: The example with $\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2}$ was invented( discovered) by Cauchy, it's rather amazing.